# Using a state string as a className with React using modular CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using [CSS modules in a React project](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules). I would like to be able to use `className={this.state.boxClassName}` in my first returned div, rather than hard-coding `className={classes.trigger}`, as you can see I have done below.

However, when I do this, upon inspecting the page in chrome, the div (which is just a css-styled square) does not receive the proper reference to the css file.

When using the `this.state` version, I see `<div class="classes.trigger">` and no square, whereas when I hard code it, I see, correctly, `<div class="Box__trigger__9jAXL">` (this format with a hashed ending comes from the way css modules in React is configured) and the square properly rendered.

How, then, can I work around this, to be able to refer to the state for the className, given the use of css modules? I'm new and this is my first question here, so thanks for bearing with me, and any assistance is much appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './Box.css';

class Box extends Component {
    state = {
        boxClassName: 'classes.trigger',
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className={classes.trigger}>
                <div className={classes.box} />
            </div> 
        );
    }
}

export default Box;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `boxClassName` to just be the key you want to access from the `classes` object.

```
class Box extends Component {
    state = {
        boxClassName: 'trigger',
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className={classes[this.state.boxClassName]}>
                <div className={classes.box} />
            </div> 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Tholle, this works perfectly. I appreciate your edits to my question too, I'll keep the formatting in mind for next time.

Comment: @AlexPMnz Great! You're welcome Alex. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your only issue is that you are setting `this.state.boxClassName` to specifically the string `'classes.trigger'`, rather than the value of `classes.trigger`.

Try modifying your code to something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import classes from './Box.css';

class Box extends Component {

    state = {
        boxClassName: classes.trigger,
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className={this.state.boxClassName}>
                <div className={classes.box} />
            </div> 
        );
    }
}

export default Box;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter, that worked perfectly too.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the boxClassName to 'classes.trigger', you're setting it to that string literal, which is why it appears that way in the css. I'm not completely familiar with react-css-moduels, but you should be able to set `boxClassName = classes.trigger` (without the quotes)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write your suggestion, Jeremy. I had a play around with it but somehow couldn't get it to work, though Tholle's answer did the trick. Also, you were right about not using the quotes - Peter's answer which suggested the same thing (but used `boxClassName: classes.trigger` rather than '=') also worked perfectly.